# Able to download package in R but not call it from library?

Tags: r, installation, dependencies, package, quartz-graphics

I was able to download the package "LMERConvenienceFunctions"

```
The downloaded binary packages are in
/var/folders/2p/3h5yk1gx4fs1gd8gtdbhdd900000gn/T//RtmpHvJyRm/downloaded_packages
```

However when I try to call it using:

```
library(LMERConvenienceFunctions)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rgl', details:
call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
error: unable to load shared object'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so': dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so, 6): 
Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libGLU.1.dylib 
Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so
Reason: image not found
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘LMERConvenienceFunctions’
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Nope it isn't–would that help?

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you have tried to install the "LMERConvenienceFunctions" package without also downloading it's dependencies? Running

`install.packages("LMERConvenienceFunctions")`

and then just using `library(LMERConvenienceFunctions)` worked for me in this case. If this still doesn't work, try manually installing rgl

Comment: Still isn't working for me. By that do you mean manually installing another package?

Comment: I was able to install rgl but again not call it from the library:

I was able to install it, but got a similar error when I tried to call it from the library:

        Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rgl', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so':

Comment: Rest of error:

dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so, 6): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libGLU.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so
  Reason: image not found
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rgl’

Comment: by manually installing, I mean that you need to run `install.packages("rgl")` first. Probably a bit clumsily stated by me. Your error tells you that LMERConvenienceFunctions won't run because it cannot load up rgl, which it depends on to run properly.

Comment: Ah gotcha thanks. I get the same sort of error. In both cases error: unable to load shared object...Reason: image not found.

Comment: Could you try with a different package to say, `install.packages("jsonlite")` and then do `library(jsonlite)`? I'm not sure I understand if it's the download that's the problem or your library function. Can you load any other packages in?

Also, what R version are you running? use `R.Version()` if you don't know it off the top of your head

Comment: Hmm interesting. I can install and call that package no problem.

I just updated R so I'm using: R version 3.2.4 (2016-03-10)

I really appreciate the help!

Edit: I found this https://chenghanyu.wordpress.com/2015/07/24/install-rgl-package/  I'm trying to download XQuartz now

Comment: if you can download other packages and get them up using the library function then I suggest just deleting the folder/file path you had originally stored LMERConvenienceFunctions in and retry. Make sure you also install any dependencies that LMERConvenienceFunctions (rgl, etc) requests, if it doesn't already download them automatically.

If that doesn't work then I don't have any more (good) suggestions.

Comment: My problem turned out to be that I didn't have XQuartz installed. It works now. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 2):

My issue turned out to be that I didn't have XQuartz installed. It can be downloaded here: http://www.xquartz.org/

After installing it, rgl began to work, and then LMERConvenienceFunctions finally started working as well. The whole process took a few tweaks so I'm pasting the entire code below. Note that this is after installing XQuartz.

```
install.packages("LMERConvenienceFunctions")
install.packages("devtools") #not sure if this is necessary, but doing this before rgl was recommended on another answer on here#
library(devtools)
install.packages("rgl")
rgl.useNULL=TRUE #little thing I had to do even after installing XQuartz#
library(rgl)
library(LMERConvenienceFunctions)
```