# can no longer install package LMERConvenienceFunctions

Tags: r, lme4, install.packages

I can no longer seem to install the package LMERConvenienceFunctions, I have done the standard:

```
 install.packages("LMERConvenienceFunctions")
 library(LMERConvenienceFunctions)
```

but it no longer works. Also, the solution offered here - [Able to download package in R but not call it from library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36096132/able-to-download-package-in-r-but-not-call-it-from-library) -  for someone who could install it but not load it doesn't work for me.

Any ideas?

when attempting to install the package I get the following error messages:

> configure: error: X11 not found but required, configure aborted. 
>   ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgl’
>      * removing ‘/home/peter/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/rgl’
>      Warning in install.packages :
>        installation of package ‘rgl’ had non-zero exit status
>      ERROR: dependency ‘rgl’ is not available for package         ‘LMERConvenienceFunctions’
>       * removing ‘/home/peter/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library      /3.3/LMERConvenienceFunctions’
>       Warning in install.packages :
>         installation of package ‘LMERConvenienceFunctions’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: Imagine taking your car to a car shop. How diagnostic will the statement "car doesn't work" to the mechanic? This translates to coding as well. Please narrow down your problem. State exactly what the problem is. At this point, you should have searched the internet for any possible error or warning you may get.

Comment: @Roman Luštrik - You are a troll. The reason you take your car to a "car shop" (though I would take it to a mechanic) is because you're not qualified to evaluate the problem yourself - perfectly reasonable. Please don't comment if you don't have anything constructive to contribute.

Comment: Peace. Do you have any error message?

Comment: @Vincent Bonhomme, thaks for your interest. I've edited the post to include the error message. Cheers.

Comment: Apparently @Roman's request was not so trolling ;-)

Comment: @VincentBonhomme it's not what he said it's the way he said it ;)

Answer (score 1):

From your error message, we can read that apparently you're running in a Mac environment and [X11](https://www.xquartz.org/) needs to be reinstalled. Then, `rgl` will not fail again, and `LMERConvenienceFunctions` (which depends on it) install should be fixed as well.

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu, but I'll give it a try.

Comment: is there a linux alternative to the software you suggest?

Comment: no idea but apparently that the first crack in the pipe